# あっちゃいけない - Grammatical origin

Tags: grammar, words, colloquial-language, idioms, contractions

あっちゃいけない

I can find multiple example sentences for this but no explanation :

そのための売買市場がなぜあっちゃいけないんだろうね？

私だけが特別であっちゃいけないんです

そしてその権力者に仕える指導者たちもまた権力を振りかざすのがたまらなく好きだ43いいか、おまえたちは、そうであっちゃいけない！

The meaning appears to be : "To not have the right to"

My guesses are : あちらいけない contraction = can't go there = "you can't go there, you don't have the right to" (idiom)

Or something like しちゃいけない (you must not do) but with ある = it must no be

-->あってはいけない ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

あっちゃいけない is a very simple contraction of あってはいけない, yes. 'There must not be'. In a couple of your sentences it's である, so for example 'I shouldn't be the only one who's special', 'Why shouldn't there be a market for that purpose?', 'You lot can't be like that!'

Comment: thanks mate ! I wonder how I could not find an answer even on this page in previous questions; this phrase felt unnatural to me like in the "special one" example (which is the one I came upon), it felt weird to see ある when describing someone state. But thanks now i get it